# Android Studio 0.8.6 upgrade to 0.8.9 Failed to apply patch

Tags: android-studio, upgrade

```
 A file operation failed.
 This might be due to a file being locked by another
 application. Please try closing any application
 that uses the files being updated then press 'Retry'.
```

I get this error code while upgrading Android Studio from 0.8.6 to 0.8.9. How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

disable any anti-virus software (if u have). restart computer. run android studio as administrator and try updating again.